# How to call an asynchronous service N times

Tags: angularjs

### Promise in ForEach

I'm having a problem, I need to call a service N times and I've tried this:

This is my function that calls the service, I send a parameter that is "code" and returns a promise.

```
var get222 = function(codigo) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var cbOk = function(response) {
            //console.log(response);
            defer.resolve(response);
        }

        var cbError = function(error) {
            //console.log(error);
            defer.reject(error);
        }

        VentafijaAccessService.getProductOfferingPrice(codigo, cbOk, cbError);
        return defer.promise;
}
```

After this function, I get the codes and I need to make a call N times and when they finish returning the promise to get the answer for each code I send.

```
var getProductOfferingPrice = function(_aCodigoOfertas) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var results = [];

        var promises = [];

        angular.forEach(_aCodigoOfertas, function(codigo) {
            promises.push(get222(codigo));
        });

        $q.all(promises)
            .then(function(results) {
                // here you should have all your Individual Object list in `results`
                deferred.resolve({
                    objects: results
                });
            });

        return deferred.promise;

    };
```

The calls to the services IF THEY ARE EXECUTED, but never returns the promise, I can not get the response of each one.

**EDIT**

VentaDataService.js

```
var get222 = function(codigo) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        VentafijaAccessService.getProductOfferingPrice(codigo, resolve, reject);
    });
}

var getProductOfferingPrice = function(_aCodigoOfertas) {
    return $q.all(_aCodigoOfertas.map(function(codigo) {
        return get222(codigo);
    }));
};
```

VentaFijaController.js

```
var cbOk2 = function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}

var cbError2 = function(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

VentafijaDataService.getProductOfferingPrice(codigoOfertas)
    .then(cbOk2, cbError2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to wrap a new promise around this.  Just return the `$q.all()` promise:

```
VentafijaAccessService.getProductOfferingPriceAllPromise = function(_aCodigoOfertas) {
    var promises = [];

    angular.forEach(_aCodigoOfertas, function(codigo) {
        promises.push(get222(codigo));
    });

    return $q.all(promises);
};
```

The resolved value of the returned promise will be an array of results.

```
VentafijaAccessService.getProductOfferingPriceAllPromise(...).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

If `_aCodigoOfertas` is an array, you can further simply `getProductOfferingPrice` to this:

```
VentafijaAccessService.getProductOfferingPriceAllPromise = function(_aCodigoOfertas) {
    return $q.all(_aCodigoOfertas.map(function(codigo) {
        return get222(codigo);
    }));
};
```

---

You can also vastly simplify `get222()` to this:

```
var get222 = function(codigo) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject)) {
        // call original (non-promise) implementation
        VentafijaAccessService.getProductOfferingPrice(codigo, resolve, reject);
    });
}
```

---

Then, in the controller, you could do this:

```
VentafijaDataService.getProductOfferingPriceAllPromise(codigoOfertas).then(function(result) {
     console.log(result);
}).catch(function(e) {
     console.log('Error: ', e);
});
```

Comment: For some strange reason, I see the execution in the Network tab but never enters either the then or the catch of the call: /

Comment: @sioesi - You'd have to add to the end of your question exactly what code you're using that has that problem.  I can't debug without seeing exactly what code you're running.

Comment: @sioesi - In the controller, you have to change `VentafijaDataService.getProductOfferingPrice(codigoOfertas)` to your new function `getProductOfferingPrice(codigoOfertas).then(...).catch(...)`.  You're calling the old version of the function, not the new one.

Comment: Function getProductOfferingPrice in VentaFijaDataService

Comment: @sioesi - The function `getProductOfferingPrice()` that YOUR code defined is just a plain function.  It's not `VentafijaDataService.getProductOfferingPrice()`.  That's the old implementation.  See how I've changed my answer to make it easier for you to do it correctly.

Comment: I'm going to edit my question so you understand my structure.

Comment: @sioesi - Your edits did not change anything of consequence.  `VentafijaDataService.getProductOfferingPrice()` is not the NEWLY defined function you created.  That's the old implementation that doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Can you go to a chat? It turns out that it still does not work, apply your answer but I only see that calls are made, I can not get the results.

Comment: @sioesi - Great, glad I could help.